# How to run certain .COM files on Amstrad CPC6128?

Tags: cpc

I have obtained Amstrad CPC6128 with Locomotive BASIC 1.1. Everything works fine except one thing.
I don't know **how to properly run certain .COM files**. I have tried general commands such as RUN or LOAD with no luck. The files for some reason are not visible from CP/M with DIR command. Probably because the disc is in DATA FORMAT?

EDIT - Clarification:
The CPC6128 computer comes preloaded with Locomotive BASIC 1.1 in ROM. All files on all formats of discs, including the .COM files in question are accessible on discs from this BASIC with CAT command.

I do have AMSDOS.COM on some discs but it's the same story. It's a .COM file I'm asking about how to run properly. If I run the AMSDOS from CP/M it seems to just go back to BASIC. I don't care about AMSDOS if I don't need it.

The CP/M version is 2.2. In this version of CP/M that I have the files can't be listed with DIR command if they are on a "DATA FORMAT" discs. I can only list the files if they are on a "SYSTEM FORMAT" disc.The discs were verified with a DISCKIT2.COM that I run from the CP/M disc.

To clarify - the .COM files I want to run are on a floppy disc which is formatted in a "DATA FORMAT". I can list files with CAT in BASIC 1.1 but not DIR in CP/M 2.2.

EDIT 2: Turns out everything works with CP/M Plus. I was using CP/M 2.2 before.

Comment: It might be helpful if you add what your setup (OS, etc) is as well as what the disk is you want to load from - and mos important o what base you know about a file being there despite not being shown?

Comment: The answer to your first question is in my original post. It's Amstrad CPC6128 with Locomotive Basic version 1.1. Regarding the disc, I have several different programs, all in .COM format on different 3" discs that were originally used with this computer. Regarding the file, I know about it from CAT command in BASIC. This command lists all the files on the disc.

Comment: To start with, you may want to add the clarification (which was not in the question!) to the question, not in comments. Second, BASIC uses AMSDOS, not CP/M. So it is important do describe what is seen under which operating system. Otherwise it's hard to guess where  you're issue is originated.

Comment: I've added an edit to my question with all the clarification I could come up with. Please let me know if there are any other ambiguous or missing info you'd like me to add.

Comment: If under CP/M 2 you type `STAT *.COM` do the files show up then? (You will need a copy of STAT.COM). If they do show up but with their names in brackets then they have been set as system files.

Comment: Are you aware that CP/M has the concept of a "user" that marks directory entries with a 4 bit number? See the last paragraph on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M#File_system). Depending on the current user, not all files are accessible.

Comment: I cannot use STAT on this disc for two reasons. 1) it doesn't exist on this disc and 2) it would not read anyway, just like all the other files on this disc under CP/M.

Comment: Since the files appear under BASIC+AMSDOS with the `cat` command you know their names. What happens when under CP/M you just type the name of one those files, without anything before (no `RUN`, no `LOAD`)? Just type the name of one of the COM files and press the return key.

Comment: Aside question: where did these disks come from? Is there any chance that they've been produced by somebody who didn't realise the disk formatting requirements for running under CP/M and has written them to the wrong sort of disk format? E.g. by downloading software they want, using a tool to construct and write an Amstrad disk image? Obviously the motivation for my question being whether the answer to yours might be "move the files to a properly-formatted disk".

Comment: Actually, AmsDos "data" format disks should be perfectly readable by Amstrad CP/M. If you cannot see files, probably the disk is corrupted or the files are stored with a different USER. Another difference is obviously you cannot boot from them

Comment: To answer some of your questions:
@StéphaneGourichon - I tried runing them as any other regular .COM file with no luck.

Comment: @thebusybee - I was vaguely aware of existance of users. I will investigate that furher. If it turns out that's the reason I will update my answer bellow.

Comment: @tofro same as thebussybee above. Will let you know.

Comment: @Tommy - the origin of this disc is unknown. I have it in my posession for few decades as a "collectible". Only now when I got this computer I was able to read it.

Comment: "I tried runing them as any other regular .COM file with no luck." Okay you tried, but my question is "What happens?". E.g. drive activity? Similar to drive activity on .COM files that work? Shorter? Longer? An error message about a file not found? Another error message? Did the OS hang? Did you get back to the prompt? Whatever you can precisely describe can hint to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After downloading CP/M Plus and copying it onto a spare floppy the *.COM files in question are visible and accessible. Apparently there are some differences in file system handling between CP/M 2.2 and CP/M Plus. The disc i was trying to read off was probably created in CP/M Plus and therefore was (for unknown to me reason) unreadable in CP/M 2.2.
Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 5):

These files are indeed intended to be executed from CP/M. AMSDOS.COM, for example, is intended to return to the "native" AMS environment from CP/M.

Likely, you'll be having the following files:

- CLOAD.COM - Allows to load a file from cassette into the computer and transfer it to disk
- CSAVE.COM - The opposite of the above
- CHKDISC.COM - byte-by-byte compare of two disks
- DISCCHK.COM - same as above, but but for use when you have only one drive
- COPYDISC.COM - what the name says, for two drive operation
- DISCCOPY.COM - same as above, but for one single drive
- FILECOPY.COM - copy files between disks and user areas, for single-drive usage (as opposed to PIP.COM)
- FORMAT.COM - what it says...
- SETUP.COM - Allows to set some boot parameters on CP/M disks

Why your disk is in "DATA" format  is likely a different question. Probably, because the DATA format provides the highest capacity, or, maybe someone has copied these files not knowing they need to be on a CP/M disk.

Why you cannot seem to be able to read the disk at all from CP/Mis yet another question: Disks in DATA format should be perfectly readable from CPM. (Are you trying to boot from that disk? That won't work. To read such a disk, start CPM with a CP/M disk in the drive, change disks, then do a DIR.)

Comment: Thank you for your input. To answer your question, no, I was not trying to boot from it. I booted from other disk with CP/M 2.2 and that might have been the problem. After booting from CP/M Plus everything works as intended.

Answer (score -2):

Indeed, AMSDOS.COM is the opposite of |CPM.
See the book [Soft158A](https://www.cpcwiki.eu/index.php/Soft158A:_DDI-1_Firmware_-_The_Complete_CPC_464_DOS_ROM_Specification) chapter 4.1.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.